# Sonar Maven Plugin fails to connect to Oracle DB using password as Maven Parameter

Tags: maven, sonarqube, maven-3, sonarqube-scan

I want to run an analysis for my PL/SQL project via Maven. I use this version of plugin:

```
<groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.4.0.905</version>
```

Using `mvn sonar:sonar` goes well until connecting to DB to retrieve data dictionary information. After running `mvn -X sonar:sonar` I'm getting the following stacktrace:

```
[DEBUG] 13:26:02.222 Unable to decrypt property sonar.plsql.jdbc.password
org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecDispatcherException: org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.PlexusCipherException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.DefaultSecDispatcher.decrypt (DefaultSecDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.PropertyDecryptor.decrypt (PropertyDecryptor.java:56)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.PropertyDecryptor.decryptProperties (PropertyDecryptor.java:45)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerFactory.createGlobalProperties (ScannerFactory.java:76)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.PlexusCipherException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.PBECipher.decrypt64 (PBECipher.java:193)
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.DefaultPlexusCipher.decrypt (DefaultPlexusCipher.java:72)
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.DefaultSecDispatcher.decrypt (DefaultSecDispatcher.java:96)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.PropertyDecryptor.decrypt (PropertyDecryptor.java:56)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.PropertyDecryptor.decryptProperties (PropertyDecryptor.java:45)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerFactory.createGlobalProperties (ScannerFactory.java:76)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy (Native Method)
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.PBECipher.decrypt64 (PBECipher.java:181)
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.DefaultPlexusCipher.decrypt (DefaultPlexusCipher.java:72)
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.DefaultSecDispatcher.decrypt (DefaultSecDispatcher.java:96)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.PropertyDecryptor.decrypt (PropertyDecryptor.java:56)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.PropertyDecryptor.decryptProperties (PropertyDecryptor.java:45)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerFactory.createGlobalProperties (ScannerFactory.java:76)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[DEBUG] 13:26:02.284 Unable to decrypt property sonar.plsql.jdbc.password
org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecDispatcherException: org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.PlexusCipherException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.DefaultSecDispatcher.decrypt (DefaultSecDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.PropertyDecryptor.decrypt (PropertyDecryptor.java:56)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.PropertyDecryptor.decryptProperties (PropertyDecryptor.java:45)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerFactory.createGlobalProperties (ScannerFactory.java:76)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerFactory.create (ScannerFactory.java:61)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.PlexusCipherException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.PBECipher.decrypt64 (PBECipher.java:193)
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.DefaultPlexusCipher.decrypt (DefaultPlexusCipher.java:72)
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.DefaultSecDispatcher.decrypt (DefaultSecDispatcher.java:96)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.PropertyDecryptor.decrypt (PropertyDecryptor.java:56)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.PropertyDecryptor.decryptProperties (PropertyDecryptor.java:45)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerFactory.createGlobalProperties (ScannerFactory.java:76)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerFactory.create (ScannerFactory.java:61)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy (Native Method)
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.PBECipher.decrypt64 (PBECipher.java:181)
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.DefaultPlexusCipher.decrypt (DefaultPlexusCipher.java:72)
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.DefaultSecDispatcher.decrypt (DefaultSecDispatcher.java:96)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.PropertyDecryptor.decrypt (PropertyDecryptor.java:56)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.PropertyDecryptor.decryptProperties (PropertyDecryptor.java:45)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerFactory.createGlobalProperties (ScannerFactory.java:76)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerFactory.create (ScannerFactory.java:61)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

I set `sonar.plsql.jdbc.password` in `pom.xml` as `${settings.servers.db-dev.password}` and this parameter is set in my `settings.xml` file. I double-checked that Maven reads the right `settings.xml` file.

And actually in the very end of an output I get `logon denied` error from db which means that plugin tried to connect (did it used `${settings.servers.db-dev.password}` as a plain text password?) to db though earlier it failed to get a password.

So my questions are:

1. Why can't Maven Plugin take a password via parameter string? I'm curious because he's okay with passing `username` as parameter string. (And it doesn't matter if my password is maven encrypted or plain text)
2. If it is known behaviour then are there any other approaches to keep your db password encrypted and also to pass it to sonar maven plugin?

**UPD**: Here's my `pom.xml` piece with servers-extension:

```
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>com.github.shyiko.servers-maven-extension</groupId>
                <artifactId>servers-maven-extension</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
```

And here's a piece of Sonar configuration:

```
        <sonar.login>${spdb-beholder.sonar.login}</sonar.login>
        <sonar.host.url>${spdb-beholder.sonar.host}</sonar.host.url>
        <sonar.plsql.jdbc.url>${liquibase.url}</sonar.plsql.jdbc.url>
        <sonar.plsql.jdbc.user>${settings.servers.db-dev.username}</sonar.plsql.jdbc.user>
        <sonar.plsql.jdbc.password>${settings.servers.db-dev.password}</sonar.plsql.jdbc.password>
        <sonar.plsql.jdbc.defaultSchema>${liquibase.user.owner}</sonar.plsql.jdbc.defaultSchema>
        <sonar.projectName>spdb-beholder</sonar.projectName>
        <sonar.projectKey>spdb-beholder</sonar.projectKey>
        <sonar.plsql.file.suffixes>sql,vw,pkb</sonar.plsql.file.suffixes>
        <sonar.sources>src/main/resources/migration/compiled</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.tests>src/main/resources/migration/tests</sonar.tests>
        <sonar.plsql.jdbc.driver>${liquibase.driver}</sonar.plsql.jdbc.driver>
        <sonar.plsql.jdbc.driver.path>${project.build.directory}/lib/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar</sonar.plsql.jdbc.driver.path>
        <sonar.plsql.jdbc.driver.class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</sonar.plsql.jdbc.driver.class>

        <sonar.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sonar.sourceEncoding>
        <sonar.language>plsql</sonar.language>
        <sonar.coverageReportPaths>${project.build.directory}/coverage-sonar-reporter.xml</sonar.coverageReportPaths>
        <sonar.testExecutionReportPaths>${project.build.directory}/sonar-test-reporter.xml</sonar.testExecutionReportPaths>
```

I also checked if this works:

```
        <sonar.plsql.jdbc.user>${settings.servers.db-dev.username}</sonar.plsql.jdbc.user>
        <sonar.plsql.jdbc.password>unencryptedpasswordfordb</sonar.plsql.jdbc.password>
```

It doesn't. So it doesn't depend on what parameter you pass in `${}` parameter.

And I found this article: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/security/#header-6
I don't like it much because I have to keep secret key on a local machine as I also test test results publication to Sonar.

Comment: First I would suggest to upgrade to the most recent version of the plugin furthermore can you please show how you have configured the whole story? Usually you access SonarQube via an access token and never a database ?(Please explain more in detail)..Why? And what do you mean by ` take a password via parameter string? `?

Comment: Yes, I use token and host address to connect to Sonar and it works well. But when it comes to analyzing pl/sql source code (it's a Oracle Database procedural language) Sonar wants to connect to DB to fetch data dictionary stuff. By "parameter string" I meant `${settings.servers.db-dev.password}` string. I will add some extra info to the question.

Comment: I think, that https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/security/#header-6 should not bother you - it's just for sonarqube server configuration. From looking at the code of sonar-scanner-maven-plugin, each property, which has the name `password` in it, will be tried to decrypt via mavens password encryption infrastructure .. from looking at the source, I cannot see, why even unencrypted values are will be tried to decrypt

Comment: looking step by step:
if run with `mvn -x sonar:sonar` ... can you see the value from your settings.xml in the list of properties, which are handed over to the plugin execution?

Comment: @RobertKleinschmager nope, actually. Just this: `[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <mojoExecution default-value="${mojoExecution}"/>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
  <skip default-value="false">${sonar.skip}</skip>
</configuration>`
I'm afraid that `server` reference could be handled only in `configuration` tag but not in `properties` section. I also use liquibase maven plugin, it has username/password under `configuration` section it works well with `servers` even with encrypted db-password.

Answer (score 0):

accessing the server properties via `${}` expressions is not supported by maven. you can use the following extension: https://github.com/shyiko/servers-maven-extension

this questions was also answered at [How to get the values of server defined in the settings.xml to use them in my pom.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559179/how-to-get-the-values-of-server-defined-in-the-settings-xml-to-use-them-in-my-po)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this plugin and I have it. The thing is that with this plugin I can't manage Sonar to connect to database.